# Invalid twitter oauth token for Abraham's Oauth class

Tags: api, twitter, oauth

Here's my current operations:

1./ User accepts app and the app callback stores the `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` into the database (as `access_token` and `access_token_secret`). 
2./ We use a cli script to handle autoposting to twitter. We load the twitter oauth object as follows:

```
            public function post()
            {
                $consumerKey = $this->getConsumerKey();
                $consumerSecret = $this->getConsumerSecret();
                $accessToken = $this->getAccessToken();
                $accessSecret = $this->getAccessSecret();
                $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey,$consumerSecret,$accessToken,$accessSecret);
                $message = $this->getPostMessage();
                $result = $twitteroauth->post('statuses/update', array('status' =>$message));
                $this->log($result);
            }
```

Now this assumes we are using the API consumer key and secret assigned to the app and the user's stored access tokens.

The result we are getting is:

`Invalid or expired token`

I don't quite understand why we are receiving this. We are using the access token and access token secret provided to us by twitter.

I did notice that there is a `GET` parameter `oauth_verifier`. This isn't something we need to be using somewhere?

In any case, I'm not quite sure whats wrong here.

**Do I need to log in or something before doing posting?**

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct.
The problem is that the library's *Util.urlParameterParse()* method is broken.